# For loop ending before iterator reaches maximum

Tags: c, for-loop

For example when I enter 10 for s, the loop in main() runs 6 times then sums. I even printed the iterator i to check the value, and it had not reached 10 yet.

```
#include <stdio.h>
/// define sum function
int sum( int n[], int s)
    {
        int i, sum_t = 0;
        for(i=0; i<s; i++)
        {
            sum_t = sum_t + n[i];   
        }
        return sum_t;
    }
    /// main program
int main()
{
    int i, s, n[s];
    printf("Enter size of array\n");
    scanf("%d", &s);

    for(i=0; i<s; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter number %d\n", i+1);
        scanf("%d", &n[i]);
    }
    printf("%d", sum(n, s));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When you declare `n[s]`, what is the value of `s`?

Comment: Ohhh, I see now. I have to declare n[s] after I use scanf for s.

Comment: you should declare n as a pointer : int *n;
and after reading s you should allocate n : n = malloc (s * sizeof(int));

Comment: You really ought to be using the result from `scanf()` - without that, you don't know whether the conversion was successful or not.

Comment: No need to malloc. int n[s] at the right place (after scan) will do the work

Comment: I was able to make it work.

Comment: Then please post an answer for the next one to read this question.